# Non-resident alien with closer connection to another country capital gains taxes

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, tax-exemption

I am selling my U.S. vacation home and will have a capital gain of approx. $85,000.  Are there any exemptions available to reduce this amount before it is subject to the 15% tax rate?  I do not qualify for principal residence as I am only there for maximum 182 days per year.